# Is there a way to cycle through levels of a filter and generate outputs in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate report card outputs using R, but have over 200 agents (levels in my factor) that require their own report (tibble output that I can write to .csv or html).

I have included a reproducible example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
Agents <- c("A", "B", "C")
Month <- c("May", "June", "July")
Score1 <- c(5,7,1)
Score2 <- c(7,8,3)

x <- cbind(Agents, Month, Score1, Score2)
df <- as.data.frame(x)

df$Score1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Score1))
df$Score2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Score2))

Report <-  df %>% 
           group_by(Month) %>%
           summarise(Skill = mean(Score1), Attitude = mean(Score2))
```

I would like to loop through my agents, using each as a filter on the Report, and then save it as Report_agentname. I took a look at purr but can't quite get my head around the map function and my needs here.

Comment: Using `cbind` converts to matrix and matrix can have a sngle class.  Just do `df <- data.frame(Agents, Month, Score1, Score2)` instead of creating matrix and later changing thee class,  Also, in the group by, you may include the 'Agents' as well (if it is also a grouping column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `purrr` you can create your own function and save the reports as .csv or in another format you want like this:

```
my_report <- function(x) {
  Report <- df %>% 
    filter(Agents == x) %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarise(Skill = mean(Score1), Attitude = mean(Score2)) %>% 
    write_csv(paste0("Report_", x, ".csv")) ## or whatever format you prefer
}

walk(df$Agents %>% unique, my_report)
```

`walk` does not return any values. It applies the function `my_report` to the unique agents in `df`.

If you want the reports to be returned you can delete the `write_csv()` function and use:

```
my_report2 <- function(x) {
  Report <- df %>% 
    filter(Agents == x) %>% 
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarise(Skill = mean(Score1), Attitude = mean(Score2))
}

map(df$Agents %>% unique, my_report2)
```